# In django how to pass RequestContext from the url declaration?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-urls, django-context

I've some url that I want to render a template without creating a view for each one, but inside  I need a form with the csrf tag, so when the user post the form I get no csrf token becouse the template have no RequestContext render on it.

How can I render templates declare in url and use csrf without creating a view for each one

My urls.py
    path('path/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='template.html')),

The error:
    CSRF token missing or incorrect.
UserWarning: A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.
  "A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context "

Comment: I don't think the view is causing the issue with the ```csrf_token```, make sure you have the context processor  ```'django.core.context_processors.csrf'```  activated. Also if you want to add context to your view you can do: ```path('path/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='template.html', extra_context={'some_context': context })),```

Comment: TemplateView already uses a RequestContext.